# I can't ask a question because I can't proceed to choose tags when ask using "guided mode"

Tags: bug, tags, questions

Why cannot I proceed to set the tags?

I try on Chrome, Mozilla, and Internet Explorer, but I still get the same error. Because when there are no tags it will show a message under tag input text, but for my situation, there isn't. There is no problem when using traditional mode; it just bugs out or something in guide mode. Any idea?

[image: Error]

Comment: Oh didn't found the related question. Thanks for your comment. Will update it as duplicate.